# Rails db:migrate:reset producing Errno::EACCES Permission denied @unlink_internal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems, railstutorial.org

I am following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, and at certain points we are to run
`rails db:migrate:reset`
However each time I do try to do so I am faced with a permission denied error concerning the file

> development.sqlite3

I have tried the following solutions I've encountered:
`1. close all programs suspected of using said file and retry task`
`2. terminate rails console, server, editor and retry task`
`3. shut/restart pc and executing the task upon restart`
`4. executing rails db:drop`

All of which have failed to allow the command to run. The only working solution is to delete the file manually and running `rails db:migrate`

I am running

> Rails 5.0.0.1
>   Ruby 2.2.5p319
>   Sqlite3 3.14.1
>   Windows 10 Professional

My stack trace is:

> ** Invoke db:migrate:reset (first_time)
>   ** Invoke db:drop (first_time)
>   ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
>   ** Execute db:load_config
>   ** Invoke db:check_protected_environments (first_time)
>   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute environment
>   ** Invoke db:load_config
>   ** Execute db:check_protected_environments
>   ** Execute db:drop
>   ** Invoke db:drop:_unsafe (first_time)
>   ** Invoke db:load_config
>   ** Execute db:drop:_unsafe
>   Permission denied @ unlink_internal - %path%/sample_app/db/development.sqlite3
>   Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
>   rails aborted!
>   Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - %path%/sample_app/db/development.sqlite3
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1450:in `unlink'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1450:in`block in remove_file'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1458:in `platform_support'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1449:in`remove_file'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:793:in `remove_file'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:571:in`block in rm'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:570:in `each'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:570:in`rm'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/sqlite_database_tasks.rb:22:in `drop'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:136:in`drop'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:152:in `block in drop_current'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:292:in`block in each_current_configuration'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:291:in `each'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:291:in`each_current_configuration'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:151:in `drop_current'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in`block (2 levels) in '
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `call'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in`block in execute'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in`execute'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in`mon_synchronize'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in`invoke'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:38:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in`call'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in`each'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:209:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:207:in`each'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:207:in `invoke_prerequisites'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:186:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in`invoke_task'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in`each'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in`run_with_threads'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:13:in`block in run_rake_task'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:10:in`run_rake_task'
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
>
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in`'
>   bin/rails:4:in `require'
>
>   bin/rails:4:in`'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe

How can I remove this error and prevent it for future projects?

Comment: Just don't use Windows for the development!

Comment: There are a ton of similar questions on Stack Overflow, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089803/bundle-exec-rake-testmodels-throws-errnoeacces-permission-denied) one. Remember to search first. And honestly, Aleksey sounds flippant, but he's right. Install Vagrant or something like that and run a virtual instance of linux and develop in that instead of Windows.

Answer (score 12):

I get the same error using Windows 10 Pro | ruby 2.4.1 | Rails 5.1.4. I soved using:

```
rake db:drop:_unsafe
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with this command following the steps in the book on Windows 10, Ruby 2.6.0, Rails 5.2.2.  I was also using DB Browser for SQLite with that database as well.

After I closed the Browser, rails server, and everything else that was still using the database, I still received the error, even after a reboot.

In order to resolve the issue, I had to delete the development.sqlite3 file manually via Windows and then do a rails db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, my database was a new one and did not containing much data, so I just manually go to this directory of my app:

```
 my_app\db
```

and I deleted the **development.sqlite3** file, and then I ran:

```
rails db:migrate
```

worked for me !!